# Minecraft 1.8 - /Clone Commamd

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just started playing 1.8 Minecraft for the *Mac* and I was wondering "What is the Clone command?" I am making a world on 1.8 that I am showcasing all the brand new features and I was wondering what is the command for `/clone`?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, Stefan. I took the liberty of editing your question slightly, since greetings and thank yous are not needed or wanted on this site. Take a look at the [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) for a quick tutorial on how to StackExchange (so to say). As it stands, this question might not be very good, since the answer is easily found at http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#clone. If that link does not answer your question or something is still unclear, feel free to edit your question to indicate what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

The `/clone` command is used to copy a region of blocks to another location. It takes 3 sets of coordinates, and optionally a mode which can also have additional arguments.

This is the full syntax:

```
/clone <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <x> <y> <z> [mode] [mode2] [TileName]
```

The first two coordinate sets (`<x1> <y1> <z1>` and `<x2> <y2> <z2>`) are opposite corners of a cuboid for the source region, as such:

[image]

You should mouse over the block and use the "Looking At" coordinates, or press `[Tab]`, to get the coordinates of a block.

The third coordinate set is used as a place to clone the region to, the destination region. Note that the blocks will go in all 3 positive directions from this point, so you want to specify the lowest northwestern block like this:

[image]

The `[mode]` argument can be `filtered`, `masked`, or `replace`. `replace` is default and will overwrite all blocks in the destination region with those that are being cloned. `masked` is similar, but will not overwrite blocks in the destination with air. `filtered` will only clone the block that you specify in `[TileName]`.

By default the command will give an error if the source and destination regions overlap to prevent glitches and strange inconsistencies; having `[mode2]` as `force` will prevent this, and attempt to do it anyway. Setting `[mode2]` to `move` automatically fills the source region with air, to give the effect of moving rather than copying. Finally, `normal` is the default for `[mode2]`. You will only need to specify `normal` if you need to give a `[TileName]` for a `filtered` `[mode]`.